# pipenv term is not recognized

Tags: python, pip, pipenv

Recently I upgrade my python version to 3.11 and T'm trying to use 'pipenv' but i keep getting this error.
[pipenv error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lL3kY.png)

I have already installed the pipenv using pip3.
[installation of pipenv using pip3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahDSV.png)

and also added the environment variable in my pc.
[environment variable in pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbmS3.png)

I'm expecting this to happen in my pc. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0EVE.png)

but I'm not able to use this command and keep getting error. If anyone knows how to solve, please drop answer.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

When you upgraded your Python version, did you update your `Pipfile` also? The line at the end of `Pipfile` should match your new Python version or it won't work.

```
[requires]
python_version = "3.11"
```